# I have a script for tkinter but need to save the user's input and store it in a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I found this script that creates a window with numerous buttons and a text box but I'm wondering if anyone can help me gather the user's input after selecting a button or pressing the enter key after typing in the text box

```
#Import the required Libraries
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
#Create an instance of Tkinter frame
win = Tk()
#Set the geometry of the Tkinter frame
win.geometry("750x250")

#Define a function to update the entry widget
def entry_update(text):
    entry.delete(0,END)
    entry.insert(0,text)

#Create an Entry Widget
entry= Entry(win, width= 30, bg= "white")
entry.pack(pady=10)

#Create Multiple Buttons with different commands
button_dict={}
option= ["button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3", "Button 4","button 5","button 6"]

for i in option:
    def func(x=i):
        return entry_update(x)

button_dict[i]=ttk.Button(win, text=i, command= func)
button_dict[i].pack()

win.mainloop()
```

I tried to edit the "entry" portion of the code and store it as a variable but other than that I'm completely clueless on how to use the Tkinter module

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare a variable to store the input using `global`, store the text in your entry box into that variable whenever the button is clicked, and print it out.

```
#Import the required Libraries
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
#Create an instance of Tkinter frame
win = Tk()
#Set the geometry of the Tkinter frame
win.geometry("750x250")

#Define a function to update the entry widget
def entry_update(text):
   entry.delete(0,END)
   entry.insert(0,text)

#Create an Entry Widget
entry= Entry(win, width= 30, bg= "white")
entry.pack(pady=10)

#Create Multiple Buttons with different commands
button_dict={}
option= ["button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3", "Button 4","button 5","button 6"]

for i in option:
   def func(x=i):
      global input_text #declare variable
      input_text = entry.get() #get data from box
      print(input_text) #print the data
      return entry_update(x)

   button_dict[i]=ttk.Button(win, text=i, command= func)
   button_dict[i].pack()

   
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, it really helped, sorry for the late response bu8t it worked excellently, thank you for the input